# Identify chord in progression

Tags: chords, chord-progressions, acoustic-guitar

Which chord is G+B+D+E ? It is a G in the bass.

```
||||||
|*||||
*|||*|
```

On guitar it's like above displays. Is it G6?

The bass tones in the progression are A, F, G, A :|| and the progression I try to play is

Amin, Fmaj7, then this G chord that I can't identify. It's like a regular G on guitar but open E instead of G and the thinnest string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's G6. Basic G major triad (GBD) with the 6th note from the scale added. Seems like there's a progression of chords, with a static E note on the top string.

Comment: Yes. The static E note on the top string is like a "pedal tone" for every chord in the progression.